# Erro ao enviar arquivos para servidor aws s3 no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo para o servidor s3 da Amazon, segui a documentação do Laravel 5.4 que fala sobre FileSystems. Mas ele retorna o erro:

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/comercio-urbano?prefix=myfile.txt%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

**Rotas**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/test', 'TesteController@teste');
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class TesteController extends Controller
{
    public function teste()
    {
      echo '123';
      $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
      $s3->put('myfile.txt', 'Teste', 'public');
    }
}
```

**FileSystems**

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],
```

**.ENV**

```
AWS_KEY=AKIAJKD62YA24W4T5QUA
AWS_SECRET=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
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=comercio-urbano
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Estas não são suas chaves verdadeiras né (AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)? Se são, sugiro remover, pois algum usuário malicioso pode usá-las.

Comment: Não é a verdadeira, mudei algumas letras e números.

Comment: Pelo que vi do erro indicado: `unable to get local issuer certificate` problemas no certificado, está usando ssl local para enviar o arquivo? Aqui tem os códigos de erro mostrados no link do curl: `https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html`

Comment: @Evert Sim, era aí mesmo o erro, tirei os códigos do localhost e deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Já que resolveu vou postar como resposta para auxiliar outros.

Comment: Mas vc usou no servidor com ssl?

Comment: Uhum, nem precisei mudar nada no código. @Evert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar o flysystem, deve-se evitar usar o domínio `localhost`, crie um hostname para a máquina local, conforme abaixo e deve funcionar:

```
http://local.dev
```