# fopen e fputs para Amazon S3 pelo Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, libcurl, amazon-aws, laravel-5.6

Em php, é possível enviar um arquivo de imagem, obtido através do retorno de uma requisição pelo cURL, diretamente para um bucket do S3 usando os métodos do Laravel? Se sim, como fazer?

Comment: Detalhe, o Laravel possui um recurso poderoso pra se trabalhar com buckets na S3, usando [file storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem) é só setar o drive do disk para s3 e ter o ambiente configurado corretamente.

Comment: Talvez essa pergunta te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194939/erro-ao-enviar-arquivos-para-servidor-aws-s3-no-laravel

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, usei justamente esse recurso pra resolver o meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema sem usar fopen/fputs, apenas pegando o retorno do curl_exec e o usando no file storage do laravel para o armazenamento:

```
  private function FileUpload($path, $url){
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050414 Firefox/1.0.3");
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $content = curl_exec($curl);
   if (curl_error($curl)) {
     return false;
   }
   curl_close($curl);
   Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, $content);
```